# Create Application is not working properly

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this code below which should show 2 lines like so:

**Your Title**
My first Google Script UI

This is the code:

```
function helloWorld() {
  var mydoc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var application = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Your Title');
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  var helloWorldLabel = app.createLabel('My first Google Script UI');
  app.add(helloWorldLabel);
  mydoc.show(application);
}
```

But what happens is I only get the "Your Title" line and not the other line.
If i change `mydoc.show(application)` to `mydoc.show(app)`, I only get the second line but not the first line.

Please show me my error here. Thank you.

Comment: You should use HTML service instead of UI service. UI service is deprecated. http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.in/2014/12/speeding-up-htmlservice.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were creating two apps, one called app and one called application. If you change it to only one (called app), it works fine.

```
function helloWorld() {
  var mydoc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Your Title');

  var helloWorldLabel = app.createLabel('My first Google Script UI');
  app.add(helloWorldLabel);
  mydoc.show(app);
}
```